# React todo application, checkbox state changed but not reflected in UI, need to click twice to see changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

working on a ToDo app using React.

```
//Item.js
export default function Item(props) {
    const {name, done, onChange, onClick} = props;
    return (<div>
        <input type="checkbox" id={name} name={name} checked={done} onChange={onChange} />
        <label htmlFor={name}>{name}</label>
    </div>)
}
```

```
//List.js
export default function List(props) {

    const {items, ...eventProps} = props;
    return (<ul>
        {items.map(function(item) {
            const {id, ...itemProps} = item;
            return <Item key={id} {...itemProps} {...eventProps} />
        })}
    </ul>);
}
```

```
//Todo.js
export default function Todo(props) {

    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
    const [item, setItem] = useState('');

    function handleAddItem(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if(item.length === 0)
            return
        const hasItem = items.filter(function(_item) {
            return _item.name === item;
        });
        if(hasItem.length > 0)
            return
        setItems([...items, {
            name: item,
            id: 'id_' + new Date().getTime(),
            done: false
         }]);
         setItem('');
    }

    function handleChangeName(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const {value} = e.target;
        setItem(value);
    }
function handleChangeItem(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const {name} = e.target;        
        const _cItems = items.slice();
        const updateditems = _cItems.map(function(_item) {        
            if(_item.name === name) {
                return {..._item, done: !_item.done}
            }
            return _item;
        });
        setItems(function() {
            return updateditems;
        });
    }

    return (<form>
        <fieldset>
            <input type="text" name="item" id="item" value={item} onChange={handleChangeName} />
            <button id="addItem" name="addItem" onClick={handleAddItem}>+</button>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <List items={items} onChange={handleChangeItem} onClick={handleDeleteItem} />
        </fieldset>
    </form>)
```

on first render, the checkbox is untick
if user clicked, thn 'handleChangeItem' is called which in term update the 'done' attribute.
& update using 'setItems', which intrem renders 'List' -> 'Item' component with updated value, mean 'done: true'.
But the UI is still shown as unticked.
Click again on the checkbox, it is showing the tick but this time no re-render only UI gets updated. mean no render method call.

Comment: you should use `e.target.checked` to get checkbox value

Comment: if i comment the ``` e.preventDefault(); ``` line in handleChangeItem then the selection works fine, with single click